# Vue Router pass data between two components using router-link

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-props

I'm working on a SPA website and I'm trying to pass some data between two components using a router-link. 
Basically I have an "Album" component (here called Polaroid) which contains in its 'data' all the album songs' lyrics. Then I have a Song component (here called Canzone) where I want to pass dynamically the lyrics for each song, based on the clicked song obviously.

This is my code:

**routes.js**

```
import Polaroid from './components/albums/Polaroid'
import Canzone from './components/songs/Canzone.vue'

export default {

    mode: 'history',
    linkActiveClass: 'font-bold',

    routes: [

        {
            path: '/polaroid',
            component: Polaroid
        },

        {
            path: '/polaroid/:canzone',
            name: 'polaroid',
            component: Canzone
        },
    ]
};
```

**Polaroid.vue** (this is the Album component where I show the songs' list)

```
<template>
<div>
  <ul class="leading-7">
    <li v-for="canzone in this.canzoni" :key="canzone.nome" >
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'polaroid', params: { name: canzone.path } }"> {{ canzone.nome }} </router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
         data(){
             return {
                canzoni: [            // all the songs
                    {
                    nome: 'Song1',
                    path: 'song-1',
                    numero: 1,
                    testo: 'lyrics1'
                    },
                    {
                    nome: 'Song2',
                    path: 'song2',
                    numero: 2,
                    testo: 'lyrics2'
                    },
                    {
                    nome: 'Song3',
                    path: 'song3',
                    numero: 3,
                    testo: 'lyrics3'
                    },
                ],


            };
        },
    }
</script>
```

**Canzone.vue**  (this is the Song component where I want to show the song lyric dinamically)

```
<template>
<div>
     
    LYRICS HERE

    {{ $route.params.canzone }}      // not working

</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        
    }
</script>
```

How can I pass the data through the router-link? Thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: first, you don't need to use `this.` in v-for

Comment: Yeah thanks but that is not the point of my question

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use `this` in `v-for` let's fix that part first.

### UPDATED

router.js

We need to fix `router.js` as well to get a proper path.

```
    {
        path: '/polaroid/:id', // I gave a ID
        name: 'polaroid',
        component: Canzone
    },
```

So after giving the ID, we need to pass the id as well in params. Using `index` for the `id`

**main template**

```
<template>
<div>
  <ul class="leading-7">
    <li v-for="(canzone,index) in canzoni" :key="conzone.nome" >
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'polaroid', params: {id: index, canzone: canzone} }"> {{ canzone.nome }} </router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

As you see I am sending the params as a object. I guess it has much more benefits with this way. But of course you can send just the path as a string as well...

the other template

```
<template>
<div>
     
    LYRICS HERE

    {{ canzone }}      // should work

</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:{
          id:{
            type: String|Number,
            required: true,
          },
          canzone:{
            type: Object,
            required: true,
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**PS:** If your `params: {canzone: canzone.path}` then this means you are sending a `string`. So you should change the primitive prop type to `string` too...

Comment: it gives me this error: [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "canzone"

found in

---> <Canzone> at resources/js/components/songs/Canzone.vue
       <Root>

Comment: what about changing the required to `false`?

Comment: if I change it to false, canzone is undefined

Comment: No man, it continues to give me errors, I would just do it in a static way and patience.

Comment: hmm, awkward. It should be okay with the code i provided. Double check my code and yours. Maybe you are missing something. Because with my last update, I changed more then one place.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `canzone` instead of `name` in the `params` of the `Polaroid.vue`

```
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'polaroid', params: { canzone: canzone.path } }"> {{ canzone.nome }} </router-link>
```

Comment: It works but the URL is not correct, it's always like this:             http://127.0.0.1:8000/polaroid/%5Bobject%20Object%5D   instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/polaroid/name-of-the-song

Comment: it's because you are sending an object in the router.    `path: '/polaroid/:canzone',` @nicoblue

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this? a way to pass the object not in the URL?

Comment: Did you use the `canzone.path`? It's the `string`, not the `object`
`:to="{ name: 'polaroid', params: { canzone: canzone.path } }"`

Answer (score 0):

set props: true in your routes
like this

```
routes: [
    {
        path: '/polaroid',
        component: Polaroid,
        props:true
    }
]
```

to get that data you shouldn't write `{{$route.params.canzone}}` but
`{{$route.params.name}}` as 'name' is what you are passing through the route

also you don't need to create another route passing canzone as a query

but if you want to do it that way, you need to get that data
like `this.$route.query.canzone`